# Tapjacking - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, security

I'm trying to protect my app against tapjacking. We tried to implement `setFilterTouchesWhenObscured` in MainActivity, however we did a security scan and it still shows that we need to protect it againts tapjacking. This is what we implemented

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View myView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    myView.setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(true);
  }
```

And I was wondering if there is a solution in react native or if we have to use external help for that.

I also tried to implement `FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED`, but It doesn't work

I need a solution to implement in React Native to secure my app. What do people recommend or what can I do to protect it?